# Result consisted of more than one row after activating trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sample_proc(IN wr VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

SELECT some_function_with_result_code_int();

END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

and a trigger:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER sample_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE some_name VARCHAR(255);
    IF OLD.age <> NEW.age THEN
        SELECT name INTO some_name FROM test WHERE OLD.age <> NEW.age;
        CALL sample_proc(some_name);
    END IF;

END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Can't understand how updating only one row's column "age" could result in multiple row change...Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Found a workaround which i don't like very much, but it's an option. Just add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the `SELECT` statement. The whole statement should look like this: `SELECT name INTO some_name FROM test WHERE OLD.age <> NEW.age LIMIT 1;`. Which brings me to other issue: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger. Couldn't find any good answer for that in SO.